# Finding matching instances of the list by getElementsByClassName JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, getelementsbyclassname

I would like to check the list values and in the case of instanced a matching value I would like to exchange the element name. I'm trying to do it that way but it doesn't work..

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
        <div class="aa"><ul><li class="a">a</li><li class="a">b</li><li class="a">c</li></ul></div>
        <div class="aa"><ul><li class="a">s</li><li class="a">b</li><li class="a">c</li></ul></div>
        
        <script>
            function myFunction() {
                var x = document.getElementsByClassName("a")[0];
                for (var i = 0; i < x.length; ++i) {
                    if (x.getElementsByClassName("a")[i].innerHTML == "a") {
                     x[i].innerHTML = "Hello World!";
                        alert("YO");
                    }
               }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is `child` class in your `HTML`?

Comment: There should be `"a"`

Comment: Your `x` variable doesn't holds an array. It's just single DOM element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do like this, where you:

- remove `[0]` from `document.getElementsByClassName("a")[0];`
- remove `.getElementsByClassName("a")` from `(x.getElementsByClassName("a")[i].innerHTML`

That will first allow you to iterate through all `a`, and then, with `x[i].innerHTML`, test its content.

Stack snippet

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
  <div class="aa">
    <ul>
      <li class="a">a</li>
      <li class="a">b</li>
      <li class="a">c</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="aa">
    <ul>
      <li class="a">b</li>
      <li class="a">a</li>
      <li class="a">c</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("a");
      for (var i = 0; i < x.length; ++i) {
        if (x[i].innerHTML == "a") {
          x[i].innerHTML = "Hello World!";
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

If you want to get only `a` that is descendants of `aa`, try with [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Stack snippet

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
  <div class="aa">
    <ul>
      <li class="a">a</li>
      <li class="a">b</li>
      <li class="a">c</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="aa">
    <ul>
      <li class="a">b</li>
      <li class="a">a</li>
      <li class="a">c</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.querySelectorAll(".aa .a");
      for (var i = 0; i < x.length; ++i) {
        if (x[i].innerHTML == "a") {
          x[i].innerHTML = "Hello World!";
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

*If to use `getElementsByClassName()`, one need 2 loops*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
        <div class="aa">
          <ul>
            <li class="a">a</li>
            <li class="a">b</li>
            <li class="a">c</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="aa">
          <ul>
            <li class="a">s</li>
            <li class="a">a</li>
            <li class="a">c</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        
        <script>
            function myFunction() {
                var x = document.getElementsByClassName("aa");
                console.log(x.length);
                for (var i = 0; i < x.length; ++i) {
                    var y = x[i].getElementsByClassName("a");
                    for (var ii = 0; ii < y.length; ++ii) {
                        if (y[ii].innerHTML == "a" ) {
                         y[ii].innerHTML = "Hello World!";
                        }
                    }
             }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version for both dives

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
        <div class="aa">
          <ul>
            <li class="a">a</li>
            <li class="a">b</li>
            <li class="a">c</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="aa">
          <ul>
            <li class="a">s</li>
            <li class="a">a</li>
            <li class="a">c</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        
        <script>
            function myFunction() {
                var x = document.getElementsByClassName("aa");
                console.log(x.length);
                for (var i = 0; i < x.length; ++i) {
                    var y = document.getElementsByClassName("a");
                    for (var i = 0; i < y.length; ++i) {
                        if (y[i].innerHTML == "a" ) {
                         y[i].innerHTML = "Hello World!";
                        }
                    }
             }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: As you use `document.getElementsByClassName` in your inner loop, is the same as to not use the outer at all. I added a 3rd sample to my answer showing how it needs to be. Do note the inner loop's `x[i].getElementsByClassName("a")` and `var ii = 0`.